# Visual Studio 2012 : Oracle Database program using VC++ (MFC) & Oracle OCCI Library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, occi

I tried to connect the oracle XE (11.2.0.2.0) database using VC++ MFC (Visual Studio 2012). Below is a example code given at oracle website.

```
void CMFCOracleOCCIDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    const string userName = "<username>";
    const string password = "<password>";
    const string connectString = "";

    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    {
       Connection *conn = env->createConnection(userName, password, connectString);
       Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("SELECT * FROM tab");
       ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
       for(int i=1;i<20;i++){
           rs->next();
           //Below are the commented 4 lines
           /*
           string s = rs->getString(1);
           CString str2(s.c_str());
           lstBox01.AddString(str2);
           MessageBox(str2);
           */
       }

       stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
       conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
       env->terminateConnection(conn);
    }
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
}
```

In the above code while the 4 line in comment, it works fine. Otherwise it works for only one loop (i=1) and display the proper message (for only 1 time). After that, getting the below error

First-chance exception at 0x51A4CCC8 (msvcp110d.dll). After selecting the break it goes to the file xutility and function

```
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
```

1. How to solve this error?
2. Usually what is best practice to connect oracle using VC++ MFC?

**Environment :**
Windows 8.1 (64)
Oracle XE (11.2.0.2.0)
[OCCI Library : Instant Client Package - SDK: Additional header files and an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant Client
Download instantclient-sdk-nt-11.2.0.2.0.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)
Visual Studio 2012 (Debug - Configuration)

**Edit**
This error raised in-case of getString() (varchar2 field). When using integer field with getInt(), it is working fine.

Comment: Can you put "tab" table structure

Comment: Also check if your project is Multi-Threaded Debug?

Comment: @user1 "tab" is a system table. i am unable to get the structure. But it is like varchar2 field. I checked with another table with varchar2 and int. The int field is working fine and the varchar2 is creating the above said problem.

Comment: okay... answer second question. Is your project is Multi-Threaded Debug?

Comment: @user1. I don't know about the Multi-Threaded Debug. And I created the MFC application (dialog) using wizard. There i didn't enabled the Multi-Threaded Debug. In the mean time i will check how to enable that....

Comment: okay, one more thing, keep this line only  `string s = rs->getString(1);`. See if it gives the same trouble

Comment: @user1. Yes. It is giving the same error.

Comment: Is this DEBUG only problem? Does your program run under RELEASE

Comment: also, change the `Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();` line to `Environment *environment = Environment::createEnvironment("AL32UTF8","UTF8");`

Comment: @user1. In the release configuration also it gives the same error. And replaced the "createEnvironment" line. It not resolved. But the getInt() still working in the replaced code.

Comment: Did you check Multi-Threaded Debug?

Comment: @user1. I checked with all /MT, /MTd, /MD, /MDd. But the getString() does not work.

Comment: Instead of `std::string` try OCCI string data type i.e. `STRING`

Comment: do you mean UString? I tried that too. Same error raised.